# Ruby rails can't add user entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Everything seems to go fine and there's no error message when executing user.save, but it doesn't show up when indexing.

I ran the migration:

```
class AddEmailToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :string
  end
end
```

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #attr_accessor :remember_token
  attr_accessor :email
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_accessor :password_digest
  attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
 # has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

  # functions...
end
```

Here on create I fill in some sample values to test it, and it submits to views/users/create.html.erb without anything displaying in "Error: []" and the correct data shown for the fields of @user.

controllers/user_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    #require 'bcrypt'
    @user = User.new
  end

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

 def create
    #@user = User.new(user_params)
    @user = User.new(name: "di3", email:"di3@di3.com", password: "di3", password_confirmation: "di3")
    #@user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save!
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the forum!"
      #redirect_to @user
      #redirect_to users_path
    else
      #render 'new'
      render @user.error_messages.full
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

views/users/create.html.erb

```
<h1>Create user params</h1>

<%= render partial: 'layouts/header' %>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Password</th>
  </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><%= @user.email %></td>
        <td><%= @user.name %></td>
        <td><%= @user.password %></td>
        <td><%= @user.password_confirmation %></td>
      </tr>
</table>

<br/>

Error:

<%= @user.errors.full_messages %>
```

But this user index doesn't show any users at all:

views/users/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing forums</h1>

<%= render partial: 'layouts/header' %>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Password</th>
    <th>Password</th>
    <th>Password</th>
  </tr>

  <% if(@users)
    @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= user.email %></td>
        <td><%= user.name %></td>
        <td><%= user.password_digest %></td>
        <td><%= user.password %></td>
        <td><%= user.password_confirmation %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

[edit]

I ran your migration (marouenB), but now when I index users it say:

> ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError Migrations are pending. To resolve
>   this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

Running that doesn't change the message.

Running rake db:migrate:status shows:

```
 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20150328013052  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150330041328  Create model forums
   up     20150331165353  Add email to users
   up     20150404003549  Add password digest to users
  down    20150506210153  Add login to users
```

[edit]

I didn't know any changes I make to db/migration are permanent. So I fixed it by recreating the old migration file with the same date stamp. Then I had to remove the contents of the change in your migration because it was already creating those fields. I had to

```
drop_table :users
```

because it was giving an error for all those nil fields. Now I have a new question but this one is solved.

Comment: Are you sure the migration works? Also, what shows the log?

Comment: You did not tell Rails to which table it should add the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First open rails console using this command : rails console

Then check for existent users in your database : users = User.all
If there is existent user 
remove the if condition line from the index view, it's not needed and use this code instead.

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
 <tr>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.password_digest %></td>
    <td><%= user.password %></td>
    <td><%= user.password_confirmation %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

First, you should fix the migration. Rails provide a shortcut to generate migration by using the syntax AddXXToYY followed by your attributes where YY is your table name. So for your case use the following command:

```
rails g migration AddLoginToUsers name:string email:string password:string
```

note that you don't need to add password_confirmation in your database so to test this validation add this to your User model

```
validates :password, confirmation: true
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
```

It will add a password_confirmation as virtual attribute only for validation.
 Now you can test the changes but note that the minimum password length is 6 so you have to change your user test data inside your controller or use your form as normal. Final check, copy the view block that I posted in the answer.

Comment: users = User.all shows a lot of created users but all have email = nil and don't have the name or password fields. does the field added to the table depend on the migration name (AddEmailToUsers) or did I not write it correctly?

Comment: I ran your migration, but now when I index users it say: [check edited message above]

Comment: first did you run this command after adding the migration file: "rake db:migrate" ? , well for your case it seems that you have deleted some migration files by hand and from your status output I don't see a migration file for user. One trick that may be usefull that you check your database for schema_migrations table than delete the row that reffers to your delete migration file.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing delimiters:

```
<% if(@users) %>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
```

Actually, I don't think the `if` is needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are problems in your create action.

```
 def create
   #@user = User.new(user_params)
   @user = User.new(name: "di3", email:"di3@di3.com", password: "di3", password_confirmation: "di3")
   #@user = User.new(params[:user])
   if @user.save!
     log_in @user
     flash[:success] = "Welcome to the forum!"
     #redirect_to @user
     #redirect_to users_path
   else
     #render 'new'
     render @user.error_messages.full
   end
 end
```

1. save! will raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid exception instead of returning a boolean value if @user is invalid. And ruby if will treat it as true.
2. No template rendered or redirection.
3. If you add "p @user.errors" to your if and else statement, you will find your password is too short.

I am wondering the following code will work or not. If it works, where is the doc? thanks.

```
render @user.error_messages.full
```