# Ruby rails undefined method 'name' @user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get the error when trying to display a sign up form:

```
undefined method `name' for `#<User id: nil, created_at: nil,
updated_at: nil, email: nil>
```

> Extracted source (around line #8):
>
> 6 7 8 9 10 11

In users/new.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I comment out that one line, it works. I've defined the name field in my model:

db/migrate/....create_users.rb

```
class CreateStructure < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    def up
        drop_table :users
        create_table :users do |t|
            t.integer :id
            t.string :name
            t.string :email
            t.string :password
        end

        create_table :model_forums do |t|
            t.integer :id
            t.string :name
        end
    end
  end
end
```

But it doesn't create the fields I ask for, and only has the old fields like created_at and updated_at.

Comment: have you run `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Why are you dropping the table in the migration?

Comment: I'm dropping it because not all of the migrations could go through until I removed it in previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957738/ruby-rails-cant-add-user-entry

Answer (score 0):

The migation file has problem, please refer to [Active Record Migrations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html)

```
class CreateStructure < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def up
        create_table :users do |t|
            t.integer :id
            t.string :name
            t.string :email
            t.string :password
        end

        #It is not recommended to create two tables in one migration file.
        create_table :model_forums do |t|
            t.integer :id
            t.string :name
        end
    end

    def down
        drop_table :users
    end

end
```

then run `rake db:rollback` to drop the old user table , rerun `rake db:migrate`

Comment: I can't rollback to this file because it is the very first migration file. I previously deleted it and had to remake it by hand. In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957738/ruby-rails-cant-add-user-entry I don't understand why it isn't adding those fields I asked for?